# Invoking a CCK widget in a custom module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm trying to find a good example or tutorial of how to include a content_taxonomy_autocomplete field within a custom Drupal module?  I haven't found anything like it... I've found some that show how to create one for a custom module, but as the field already exists, I just want to reuse it in my custom module, but can't seem to find anything on how to use that field in a custom module?  If someone can point me to something that would work, that'd be great...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to [reuse CCK widgets in custom forms](http://groups.drupal.org/node/16542). But building an autocompleting taxonomy field yourself is really simple. You only need a textfield with [#autocomplete_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#autocomplete_path) in your $form, a callback for this path defined in [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) and the callback itself. 
http://drupal.org/node/42552 is oudated. Search for "Drupal 6 autocomplete". There are loads of tutorials like [this](http://www.chrischen.me/content/drupal-using-autocompletepath-textfield-elements).